# Make TextView appear above another TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am trying to make 2 TextViews apear above each other through code.

My question is: how can I stack them over each other?

Sample Code

```
private TextView DurationView;
private TextView DurationViewoverall;

DurationView = new TextView(getContext());
    DurationView.setText("");
    addView(DurationView);


    DurationViewoverall = new TextView(getContext());
    DurationViewoverall.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    DurationViewoverall.setText("");
    addView(DurationViewoverall);
```

I am trying to have `DurationView` appear above `DurationViewoverall`.
The class they are in extends Linear Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add LayoutParams to the textview and make your linear layout as orientation vertical

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

DurationView = new TextView(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams durationViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
DurationView.setLayoutParams(durationViewParams);
DurationView.setText("Text1");
linearLayout.addView(DurationView);


DurationViewoverall = new TextView(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams durationViewoverallParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
DurationViewoverall.setLayoutParams(durationViewoverallParams);
DurationViewoverall.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
DurationViewoverall.setText("Text2");
linearLayout.addView(DurationViewoverall);

addView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: This comes closer but it sets all textViews in the list item into vertical layout. Not just the 2 listed.

Comment: So you have multiple item..? and its orientation is horizontal..?

Comment: Yes there are more items which orientation shouldn't be changed. Just these 2.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the LinearLayout is set to have a vertical orientation. If that is set properly, you may need to set the LayoutParams of the TextViews programatically as well.

Comment: Is there a way to set the LayoutParams to vertical orientation for just the 2 textviews? Since there is more then just the 2 textviews.